# How to get and stack frames from live video and use LSI algorithm

Tags: python, filter, temporal, ximea

I have a camera XIMEA and I want to make algorithm that could get and stack number of frames with my algorithm in real time. 
For example, we have a live video. after 15-th frame I want to get [1,15] frames in one list (List comprehension?) and make something with them. After that I want to get a list with frames [2,16], [3,17] etc while I won't stop it. How can I do that? 
I have a code like that for camera

```
import cv2
import time
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
from scipy import ndimage

cam = xiapi.Camera()
cam.open_device()
img = xiapi.Image()
```

now you see what libraries I used for it. 
LSI algorithm (temporale filter) is about to get mean value for one pixel in a few frames (in my case in 15). Should I use some numpy functions for pictures as for arrays or opencv for frames?